# extracting case classes with scala lift-json when json is variable

Tags: scala, lift-json

I'm trying to extract the following json values

```
// a 'Change item with a list of values
{
      "@count":"2",
      "change":[{
        "@webLink":"http://localhost:8080/viewModification.html?modId=6&personal=false",
        "@version":"b51fde683e206826f32951750ccf34b14bead9ca",
        "@id":"6",
        "@href":"/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:6"
      },{
        "@webLink":"http://localhost:8080/viewModification.html?modId=5&personal=false",
        "@version":"826626ff5d6bc95b32c7f03c3357b31e4bf81842",
        "@id":"5",
        "@href":"/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:5"
      }]
    }

// a 'Change item with a single value
{
      "@count":"1",
      "change":{
        "@webLink":"http://localhost:8080/viewModification.html?modId=8&personal=false",
        "@version":"803f9c1cd2c553c3b3fb0c950585be868331b3b1",
        "@id":"8",
        "@href":"/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:8"
      }
}
```

I have the following case classes

```
case class ChangeItem(`@count`: String, change: List[ChangeItemDetail]) {
  def this(`@count`: String, change: ChangeItemDetail) = this(`@count`, List(change))
}
case class ChangeItemDetail(`@webLink`:String, `@version`:String, `@id`:String, `@href`: String)
```

but with lift-json only the JSON example with multiple items seems to work, the single item throws.

```
      parse(listEx).extract[ChangeItem] // OK
      parse(singleEx).extract[ChangeItem] // throws
```

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to "fix" the JSON by transforming it to a uniform format.

```
val json = parse(origJson) transform { 
  case JField("change", o: JObject) => JField("change", JArray(o :: Nil)) 
}

json.extract[ChangeItem]
```

That will work in both cases.

Comment: Is there any way to encode this info in the case class, so that the parsing parse/extract code can be generic?

Comment: No, but I do not see a problem here. You already know which type to extract, just transform the JSON at that point.